# Launch program then attach debugger

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012, add-in

I'm trying to writing a visual studio plugin that launches the application to be debugged with out the debugger attached, and after some delay attach the debugger automatically to the process.

The reason I wish to do this is that starting my program with the debugger in a normal way takes a very long time as it seems to be taking ages when dealing with dll's even though I have disabled loading of dll symbols.

I have found plugin code that catch the debug event:

m_debuggerEvents.OnEnterRunMode += DebuggerOnEnterRunMode;

but have not found any way to launch my application as if I had hit the "start without debugging"

Answer (score 0):

string VSStd97CmdID = "{5EFC7975-14BC-11CF-9B2B-00AA00573819}";
            m_dte.Commands.Raise(VSStd97CmdID, (int)VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID.StartNoDebug, null, null);

Answer (score 0):

There is also the following

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Debug.StartWithoutDebugging")
```